# Is there a standardized way of calling a function any time a JQuery UI dialog is opened?

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have a function that I need to call anytime any dialog is opened, does anyone have any suggestions? I can't seem to find any information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open event, [read all about it here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open)

> Supply a callback function to handle the open event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

If you have multiple dialogs that need to share this behavior, wrap up the creation as a plugin like so:

```
//possible syntax errors sorry!
$.fn.dialogWithCustomOpenBehavior = function() {
    return this.dialog({
      open: function() { ... stuff ... });
    });
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't make a plugin out of that.  Better to just name the "open" callback function and re-use it.

Comment: @SamDufel Yeah that's not a bad idea either, it was just the first thing that popped in my mind when I realized I had missed the `any` bit in the question.

Comment: Haha, well it was a little ambiguous whether or not I meant anytime a specific dialog was called or anytime _any_ dialog is opened. But, it's the latter. Thanks, guys.